How to run latest Firefox (Snap) in X11/Xorg, when clicking it in the sidebar?
My time tracking software needs to access the title of windows, and Wayland doesn't allow that.
Firefox 120 was working fine, but newer Firefox versions run by default with Wayland.
How to run Firefox on X11 (or XWayland)? [see Edit below]
Everywhere is written to run
env GDK_BACKEND=x11 /snap/bin/firefox

but this won't change anything: about:support tab still reports wayland as "Window protocol".

I also tried to set
MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=0

but then Firefox won't start because of

Error: cannot open display: :0

There's 2 monitors: the main one and an external one

I'm stuck with Wayland and seems like all the options for X-Server are either ignored or broken (or requiring additional config?)
EDIT
I found out the environment variable DISABLE_WAYLAND. It finally runs via protocol XWayland when running
env DISABLE_WAYLAND=1 /snap/bin/firefox

I tried to add that flag in the Exec=.. of /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/firefox_firefox.desktop (so it's run via Xorg by all the links around the desktop system), but it seems to ignore the flag/env-var and still start Firefox in Wayland.
How to ensure that the desktop links always run in XWayland/Xorg?

You make the choice xorg/Wayland at the login prompt (click on gear icon in lower right corner).  Filrefox runs both ways for me on Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop.What Ubuntu release are you using?

Same ubuntu release. But I don't want to use Xorg for everything: only for Firefox; all other apps should stay on Wayland by default.

I found the fix, check my answer. Now Firefox runs in XWayland even tho the rest of the system is on Xorg. And the time-tracking software can track the browser again! :)

Everything is quite unintuitive, but this is how I managed to make it work.
First, the actual command to ensure that xwayland (Xorg) is used instead of wayland, there are 2 environment-variables necessary to really do it:
env MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=0 DISABLE_WAYLAND=1 /snap/bin/firefox

adding both env-vars also in the Exec section (beware, there are multiple in the Firefox .desktop file!) allowed me to run Firefox in Xorg mode either via sidebar link or via the link in the Activities (keyboard CMD/WIN button).
BEWARE: for some odd reason the changes to the desktop file might not be reflected immediately, hence try to run the app/link a few times to ensure that it works (or that it doesn't).
Also, I'm not sure if it's mandatory but I also tried to confirm the changes  via:
sudo desktop-file-install firefox_firefox.desktop
sudo update-desktop-database

Hope it will work for you as well!
And.... hopefully one day Wayland will loosen up its security model and understand that they can't forbid access to an app's window-title from other apps, because that's a big use case.
Without that, there will never be anymore a functioning automatic time-tracker on Linux 

What made it work for me was:
sudo snap connect firefox:x11

Hopefully this will work for future people as well!
Took me sometime to get it working but it's working fine for me now at least. Seems like this is the case for all snaps.
